# jQuery toggle() for radio button selects multiple at a time, needs to work like simple radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have created two radio buttons, and for both radio buttons, I used for creating `<i>` font icon. As I had created that earlier as a check box and it worked properly, I used the same code for creating the radio buttons. Fixed the position; it works if I go by the check box. For these radio buttons, I used the `toggle()` function in jQuery. But when I use the radio buttons, then I saw that I can not do one selection at a time.

```js
function togperm()
{
    $("#perm").toggle();

}
function togchq()
{
    $("#chq").toggle();

}
```

```css
.radiocirl {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.bluefont{ color:rgb(0,98,168) !important; }
.shcursor{cursor: pointer;}
.f10{font-size: 1.0em !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-12"> 
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1"> 
        <div class="radiocirl shcursor" onclick="togchq()">
          <i class="fa fa-circle f10 bluefont" id="chq" style="position: absolute; display: none; margin: 2px 0.4px;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="col-12"> Correspondence Address</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="radiocirl shcursor" onclick="togperm()">
          <i class="fa fa-circle f10 bluefont" id="perm" style="position: absolute; display: none;margin: 2px 0.4px;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>                            
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="col-12">Add Address</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope some one understand the requirement, i explain again. radio button working fine, but issue if i select one radio button and after selecting one i go for second radio button. Then i will see both the radio button got checked though  the only one radio button need to get selected at on click.

Comment: I understand the explaination, but is this intended to strictly be manual radio handling? ... if so, this appears to be the hard way to go for having more overhead to handle. Have you seen [bootstraps radio example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios)? (scroll down slightly to the radio example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` and `.not()` methods to achieve same . First you can get closest div which contains both your radio button then using `.not()` exclude div where click event has occur then simply use `hide()` to hide other `i` icon.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".radiocirl").on("click", function() {
  //get the `i` tag
  var selector = $(this).find(".bluefont")
  selector.toggle(); //toggle same
  //get closest div `outer` and find `i` tag not(the one which is inside the div which is clicked hide it)
  $(this).closest(".outer").find(".bluefont").not(selector).hide()

})
```

```css
.radiocirl {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bluefont {
  color: rgb(0, 98, 168) !important;
}

.shcursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.f10 {
  font-size: 1.0em !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--aded outer class-->
<div class="col-md-12 outer">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="radiocirl shcursor">
          <i class="fa fa-circle f10 bluefont" id="chq" style="position: absolute; display: none; margin: 2px 0.4px;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="col-12"> Correspondence Address</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-1">
        <div class="radiocirl shcursor">
          <i class="fa fa-circle f10 bluefont" id="perm" style="position: absolute; display: none;margin: 2px 0.4px;"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-11">
        <div class="col-12">Add Address</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```